# Absolute Path Problems

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

Ok so i'm writing a script that uploads a file and then publishes the file path to a mysql database. The problem i'm having is it is publish the absolute path from the root of the server. I don't have web access to this part of the server so when my other script goes to load it, it fails.

I know the issue is with this line. Its publishing:ROOT/aaaa/aaa/aaaa/aaaa/private/modernevents/uploads/image1.jpg intead of just /private/modernevents/uploads/images1.jpg

```
$targetFolder = '/private/modernevents/uploads'; // Relative to the root
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
```

Tried to remove $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and the script wouldn't work anymore

Any ideas? Im lost :/

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the cause of your problem. Specifying an absolute path instead of a relative path should not cause file access to fail, assuming both paths point to the same place. It doesn't matter that you don't have access to the directories higher up in the absolute path; all that matters is that you can access the directory (and the file) at the end. I would suggest you check and make sure that the part you're appending to the end is correct.

Comment: Well I have godaddy hosting(Yes I know) so when the script goes to display the image, I get a 404 because its trying to disply url.com/uploads/images1.jpg but its getting url.com/aaaa/aaa/aaaa/aaaa/private/modernevents/uploads/image1.jpg which doesn't exist because the url points to /html/private/modernevents/ not /aaaa/ I hope this makes sense :/ haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to store the path from /private/modernevents/uploads then don't use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Store $targetFolder.$imageName in the database.

Answer (score 1):

First, know where you are: use `__FILE__` then use `dirname()` to get the directory of your script. Then if you know the upload path relative where you are, you can construct the full path you need.